# Where is this toast coming from?

Tags: android, toast

For some reason the app that I'm working on is displaying a toast that shows the internal storage space left on my device even though I didn't code this in.

Here is a screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2ERU.png
And here is the code for the (only) activity.
http://pastie.org/8382286

As you can see, all of the toasts are commented out and I'm not even importing `android.widget.Toast`. Yet I'm still getting the toast shown in the screenshot.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and here is the manifest in case it matters.   
http://pastie.org/8382304

Comment: using your phone as an emulator or may be due to the apps cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using your phone as an emulator?
i get such message only when i use my phone as an emulator. such messages wont appear when you try running your app on any device. you get that toast only when app are run through your ide

Comment: Yes, I am. I'll try running it on a couple of other devices w/o the ide to be sure, but this seems to be the reason. Thanks!
Is this a recent feature? Because I don't remember this happening some  months ago.

Comment: thanks for accepting the answer, however i am not sure if this is a new feature of ide :) happy coding!

Answer (score 45):

I was getting the same toast notification on my Android 4.1.1 device. Turns out it was ES File Explorer that was generating the toast. It has a setting that shows low storage notifications.

You can disable it by going to Settings > Display settings > Uncheck "Show low space warning".

Comment: Just an FYI, I have been getting this toast as well and I also have ES File Explorer but the Show space low warning was disabled. so it must only be when I'm in Android Studio and I upload a file to the phone.

Comment: Yeah you are right.. I am also getting the Toast with the warning disabled. It comes when I update or install an app from Play Store.
Looks like some bug in ES file explorer.
PS: I am on a real device, not an emulator.

Comment: The same in my case, it's shown every time I install apk from Android Studio. Must be ES file explorer's bug.

Comment: @hoss, I had the same thing on my real device. Even though it was unselected it kept showing the toast. Checking and then unchecking the option seems to have fixed it for me.